# Docker-compose up problem port 443 (98: Address already in use) error logged in nginx logs

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am facing following error when I try to up my docker:

```
2019/09/27 07:53:33 [emerg] 18#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/09/27 07:53:33 [emerg] 18#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/09/27 07:53:33 [emerg] 18#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/09/27 07:53:33 [emerg] 18#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/09/27 07:53:33 [emerg] 18#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/09/27 07:53:33 [emerg] 18#0: still could not bind()
```

also when I try to access app which will run on nginx following error loged:

```
2019/09/27 07:55:54 [error] 11#0: *50 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.10.5.254, server: checkout.servername.docker, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.99.1:3000/", host: "checkout.servername.docker.uk"
```

Following is the chunk from my docker-compose.yml file:

```
  varnish:
    build: ./docker/varnish_nginx
    links:
      - apache
    volumes:
      - ./docker/varnish_nginx/varnish/default.vcl:/etc/varnish/default.vcl
      - ./docker/varnish_nginx/varnish/magento_mobile_detect.vcl:/etc/varnish/magento_mobile_detect.vcl
      - ./docker/varnish_nginx/varnish/varnish.params:/etc/varnish/varnish.params
      - ./docker/varnish_nginx/varnish/start.sh:/start-varnish.sh
      - ./logs/varnish/:/var/log/varnish
      - ./docker/varnish_nginx/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./docker/varnish_nginx/nginx/ssl/levosoft_docker.csr:/etc/nginx/ssl/levosoft_docker.csr
      - ./docker/varnish_nginx/nginx/ssl/levosoft_docker.key:/etc/nginx/ssl/levosoft_docker.key
      - ./docker/varnish_nginx/nginx/ssl/levosoft_docker.pem:/etc/nginx/ssl/levosoft_docker.pem
      - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
      - ./docker/varnish_nginx/nginx/start.sh:/start-nginx.sh
    networks:
      widgets:
        ipv4_address: 172.10.1.8
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 6082:6082
```

Comment: Possibly another  service is running on host's port 443. Try with a different port.

Comment: yes exactly this is the issue but if I change any port its not working. Also I have this issue only on Ubuntu 18 distribution on Mac its working fine

Comment: What do you mean is not working? Did you get any errors? It would be useful to share your docker compose file.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, another process is already using port 443.

To verify and find the process using it, run the following:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 443
```

Output:

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 443
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      26951/docker-proxy
```

Now that you have the process identified, you should shut that down and restart your nginx docker container that was failing.

Comment: If I kill this process and again restart my nginx container this process again get this port and after that again my nginx gave same error

Comment: I had updated my question with my docker-compose file chunk may be you get some point from it ?

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad, you should post your entire `docker-compose.yml` file however I think I know what is going on. You have a `link` to an `apache` service which will run on the same ports as nginx resulting in your current situation. For the `varnish` service, i'd suggest that you update your port mappings to `8080:80` and `8443:443` to avoid the conflict. Let me know if this works. I can update my answer if it does.

Comment: I can send t to you in email.

Comment: on changing to 8080:80 and 8443:443 I am getting error: 
ERROR: for varnish  Cannot start service varnish: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ecommerceservice_varnish_1 (d82df8849fe18dc791fafde5a3dfdccf53f961af7bedbd430828c045e22d1114): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: You should just post it in StackOverflow. If there is sensitive information, just remove it with something like ***** REMOVED ***** make it clear. In regards to the additional port conflict, you would need to change 8080 to something that is not in use (E.g., 8181). You can run `netstat -tulpn` to see what ports are in use.